# Nodejs multiple request in a row

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm developing nodejs application with users registration using sails.
I have an /signup method, which is looking for existing user, if user not found, it will create new user in db.

As you know in sails model (waterline) available few methods : beforeCreate, afterCreate. In beforeCreate I need also register user in a few other services(it takes +-2 seconds), after that I can set received data to user object.

The problem is if user clicks few times on "register" button (or just send the same request 2+ times in a row), it will create 2 objects in db ( or another services ). I have a similar with some other methods like this.

I was trying to set unique field in user model. Also maybe is good idea to implement police, witch can check user + reqest url and put this data into redis. If the second request arrives , check if it exists in Redis. Any other ideas?

Comment: if event gets fired 2 times then the node will start processing the same request 2 times. You can prevent this on client side by `disabling` the form submit button or some other techniques.

Comment: this doesn't prevent on server side. Also we have several frontend applications, so we need to fix it on backend.